# How to close all other dropdowns angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have dropdown directive with isolated scope. And I need to close all other dropdowns except current when I am clicking on it.

For now I have this code:

```
  $document.on("click", function (e) {
      scope.activeList = false;
  });
  scope.onComboboxClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Please, share your html code for batter understanding.

Comment: @Богдан Носовицкий Do you mean that if  you click on a particular dropdown the other open dropdowns should close?

Comment: I guess that's what broadcast events are for

Comment: show dropdown directive code and html also

Comment: template and directive is too big for understanding. What part are you interested in ?

Comment: @logan, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you in your code

```
 $document.bind('click', function (event) {
        var isClickedOutside = element
              .find(event.target)
              .length > 0;

        if (isClickedOutside)
           return;
        //Close the dropdownbox 
        scope.vm.isOpen = false;
        scope.$apply();
     });
```